# PhD application - including dual degree in your application and or SOP

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, transfer-student

I was wondering, what admission office values more:
I have 2 degrees, but my 2nd degree (dual degree) has a low GPA, it is lower than 3.0, but my 1st degree is above 3.0.
I know graduate admission likes to see good grades above 3.0.

1. So, should I even mention my 2nd degree? (statement of purpose)
   if I mention it, does it mean the admission office will want to see proof (transcript)?

A small note: for my 1st degree, the university gave a diploma supplement that only mentions and shows courses related to that degree. So, I am planning to use that, since it doesn't show a lower GPA that comes when combined with my 2nd major.

2. Should I include my dual degree as a separate degree earned in my application?
   (even though my GPA is lower than 3.0, it will still strengthen my application)?
3. or just make an application and mention only 1st major.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you don't mention it, what is the likely reaction of the admissions committee if they find out about it? I think honesty is always the best policy.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue since, with my 1st degree, I already satisfy their prerequisite conditions. Is it an obligation to mention all your education history?

Comment: What does your university transcript show? Usually it will show all classes taken and all degrees granted. Not providing a full transcript will not go down well if found out.

Comment: So, with the diploma comes a Diploma Supplement (it is an EU model). It works just like the normal transcript with additional details on the accreditation of the degree.